# Stopwatch with React JavaScript that starts onPageLoad

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create an auto-starting stopwatch in react js, but I keep getting the following error message:

Syntax error: this is a reserved word (82:13)

80 |     render() {
  81 |         return (
  82 |             {this.state.counter}
  83 |             {this.state.miliseconds}
  84 | 
  85 |

This is my code, will be really grateful if someone will point to mistake:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './StopWatch.css';

class StopWatch extends Component {

    state = {
        timer: null,
        counter: '00',
        miliseconds: '00',
        startDisabled: true,
        stopDisabled: false
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        
        this.onPageLoad = this.onPageLoad.bind(this);
        this.onButtonStart = this.onButtonStart.bind(this);
        this.onButtonStop = this.onButtonStop.bind(this);
        this.onButtonReset = this.onButtonReset.bind(this);
        this.start = this.start.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.start();
    }


    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.state.timer);
    }

    start() {
        var self = this;
        let timer = setInterval(() => {
            var num = (Number(this.state.miliseconds) + 1).toString(),
                count = this.state.counter;

            if (Number(this.state.miliseconds) == 99) {
                count = (Number(this.state.counter) + 1).toString();
                num = '00';
            }

            self.setState({
                counter: count.length == 1 ? '0' + count : count,
                miliseconds: num.length == 1 ? '0' + num : num
            });
        }, 0);
        this.setState({ timer });
    }

    onPageLoad() {

        this.start();
        this.setState({ startDisabled: true, stopDisabled: false });
    }

    
    onButtonStart() {

        this.start();
        this.setState({ startDisabled: true, stopDisabled: false });
    }


    onButtonStop() {
        clearInterval(this.state.timer);
        this.setState({ startDisabled: false, stopDisabled: true });
    }


    onButtonReset() {
        this.setState({
            timer: null,
            counter: '00',
            miliseconds: '00'
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            {this.state.counter}
            {this.state.miliseconds}

            <button title="Start" disabled="disabled"></button>
            <button title="Stop" disabled="disabled"></button>
            <button title="Reset" disabled="disabled"></button>
        );
    }
}

export default StopWatch;
```

```css
container {
    flex: 1;
    justify-content: 'center';
    align-items: 'center';
    background-color: '#F5FCFF';
}

counter {
    font-size: 60;
    text-align: 'center';
    height: 60;
    margin: 10;
}

miniCounter {
    font-size:20;
    position: 'relative';
    top: -32;
    right: -50;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should warp your elements in a `div`

```
render() {
    return (
     <div>
        <p>{this.state.counter ? this.state.counter : 'counter state is empty'}</p>
         <p>{this.state.miliseconds ? this.state.miliseconds : 'miliseconds state is empty'}</p>

        <button title="Start" disabled="disabled"></button>
        <button title="Stop" disabled="disabled"></button>
        <button title="Reset" disabled="disabled"></button>
     </div>
    );
}
```